# Primefaces library in spanish?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, localization

I'm using Primefaces library with Java Server Faces.

The problem is that the web app that we're developing is in spanish. And Primefaces library send me the alerts and errors in English, like this:

[image]

**Is there any way to configure Primefaces.jar to change the text of alerts outputs? or is there a primerfaces.jar library in spanish?**

Thanks.

Comment: Just to avoid the obvious, have you set JSF default locale to Spanish?

Comment: Mmmm.... Let me see.... I'm new at Java WEB

Comment: Nevermind, in case of `<p:dataTable>` the empty message is hardcoded instead of localized :( Go ahead with answer of Lamq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can custom empty message with :

`<p:dataTable ... emptyMessage="Your empty message" ... />`